# C# SQL table to text file output format

Tags: c#, sql

I've run into a bit of an issue. One of my fields row {4} has a variable length of characters. However, its ending position in the file must be 23 characters from the end of row {3}. So I need to add however much white space is necessary to equal 23 characters for row {4}. As you can see, I've tried this with a for loop. Unfortunately it does not work. I'm not sure if it's the method I'm using, or the syntax that's the problem.

```
      if ((checkResp91 != null) || (checkResp00 != null))
            {
                string selectCommandText91 = "SELECT * FROM EFT_BANK_INFORMATION1";
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter91 = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommandText91, connection))
                {
                    using (DataTable table91 = new DataTable("EFT_BANK_INFORMATION1"))
                    {
                        adapter91.Fill(table91);
                        System.Text.StringBuilder commaDelimitedText = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                        //commaDelimitedText.AppendLine("col1,col2,col3"); // optional if you want column names in first row
                        foreach (DataRow row in table91.Rows)
                        {
                            string spaceholder = "";
                            string spacer = row[4].ToString();
                            int countit = spacer.Length;
                            for (int i = countit; i < 23; i++)
                            {
                                spaceholder = spaceholder + " ";
                            }

                            string value = string.Format("{0}{1}                {0}         {2}{3}{4}{spaceholder}{5}", row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], spaceholder, row[5], row[6]); // how you format is up to you (spaces, tabs, delimiter, etc)
                            commaDelimitedText.AppendLine(value);
                        }
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl9_1_export.txt", commaDelimitedText.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Changed to

```
   //commaDelimitedText.AppendLine("col1,col2,col3"); // optional if you want column names in first row
                        foreach (DataRow row in table91.Rows)
                        {
                            string spacer = row[4].ToString();
                            string newvalue = (spacer + new string(' ', 23)).Substring(0, 23);
                            string value = string.Format("{0}{1}                {0}         {2}{3}{4}{5}", row[1], row[2], row[3], newvalue, row[5], row[6]); // how you format is up to you (spaces, tabs, delimiter, etc)
                            commaDelimitedText.AppendLine(value);
                        }
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\BillingExport\\tbl9_1_export.txt", commaDelimitedText.ToString());
                    }
                }
```

Which is giving me extra spaces for some reason, and putting them before the characters, when I need it after.

Output from the above code:

```
09                  09         011301390011111119              AAAAAAA AAAABBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB CO.
```

when it needs to be

```
09                  09         011301390011111119AAAAAAA AAAA           BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB CO.
```

Comment: string value = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}", row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], spaceholder, row[5], row[6]);

Comment: you have {spaceholder} in as a placeholder, instead of the numeric position in the argument list - {5}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to reinvent Fortran record files eh?

Just use argument lengths in your `string.Format()`:

```
string.Format("{0}{1}                {0}         {2}{3}{4,23}{5}", row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]);
```

I'd also use it to get rid of those spaces, but up to you.

Comment: Thanks. This worked, although it put the white space before the characters in the file, and I need it to be after.

Comment: @Dave, use `{4,-23}` if you want the other alignment.